# no route matches action in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am a little confused on how to set the route for a custom action. I have the following link in my view:

```
<%= link_to 'mark done', finish_task_path(task.id), :method => :post %>
```

In my tasks_controller I have:

```
  def finish
     @task = Task.find(params[:id])
     new = {:status => "done"}
     @task.update_attributes(new)
     redirect_to :action => "index"
  end
```

In my routes file I have:

```
match '/tasks/:id/finish', :to => 'tasks#finish'
```

I have also tried the following in my view:

```
    <%= link_to 'mark done', finish_task_path(task.id), :method => :post %>
```

Which also has not worked. How do I set the route correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a route, but it is not named. Does this work?

```
match '/tasks/:id/finish', :to => 'tasks#finish', :as => 'finish_task'
```

Have a look at the output of `rake routes` to ensure your routes are being declared as you want.